# SQL-query: See relationship between array of users and groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a small application where users can login and do whatever they do in there. The database structure regarding users is nothing fancy. There are three tables:

users

groups

user_group_relation

Now, How can I get a list of all the groups together with membership status for an array of users?

Let me clarify this by an example.

*David is member of **'users'**, **'administrators'**, **'economy'***
*Erik is member of **'users', administrators'***
*Richard is member of **'administrators'***
*Lisa is member of **'administrators'**, **'economy'***

Here is the result I would want from an sql-query

```
GroupName.......................isEveryoneAMember

users   ......................  someAre  
Administrators..........        yes  
Economy ..................      someAre  
Sales   ....................... no
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select g.GroupName,
    case
        when count(ug.userId) = (select count(*) from users) then 'yes'
        when count(ug.userId) = 0 then 'no'
        else 'someAre'
    end as HowMany
from Groups g
join UserGroups ug on g.id = ug.groupId
group by g.groupName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  g.name,
        CASE
        WHEN mcount = 0 THEN
                'none'
        WHEN mcount = ucount THEN
                'all'
        ELSE
                'some'
        END AS isEveryOneAMember
FROM    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*) AS ucount
        FROM    users
        ) u
CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  group_id,
                COUNT(*) AS mcount
        FROM    user_group_relation ug
        GROUP BY
                group_id
        ) ug
JOIN    groups g
ON      g.id = ug.group_id
```

Comment: Sweet. Looks really nice :)  I will try it out emideatly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicate group names:

```
WITH rollcall AS (
  SELECT
    g.name,
    ug.user_id
  FROM groups g
    CROSS JOIN users u
    LEFT JOIN user_group_relation ug ON g.id = ug.group_id AND u.id = ug.user_id
)
SELECT
  GroupName = name,
  isEveryoneAMember = CASE COUNT(user_ud)
    WHEN 0        THEN 'No'
    WHEN COUNT(*) THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'someAre'
  END
FROM rollcall
GROUP BY name
```